# how to save multiple array with help of register_setting() or other function in plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I know about `register_setting` function to save value in option table but my question is how to save multiple array inside my one option table key :

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [key1] => value1 [key2] => value2 ) 
[1] => Array ( [key1] => value2 [key2] => value4 )
)
```

**key1[] and key2[]** is textbox name which is dynamic generated.

I searched a lot but I cant get any solution.thx in advance.!!

Comment: nope i want to save array inside array in option table @vard

Comment: @vard  key1[] and  key2[]  will be textbox name

Comment: I'm not quite sure of what you try to achieve here, some more background informations could help to understand the question. Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can add a group of settings with [`add_settings_section`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_section).

Comment: ok thx @vard for help i got some search in theme setting page in wordpress admin side but not found my solution..:(..

Comment: @vard i want to save value manully is it possible with register setting?